# Ordinal Independent Variables and Dependent Variable Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, spss, survey, ordinal-data

I have 3 variables (2 are independent and 1 is dependent). All three variables are measured with questionnaires consisting of multiple questions recorded on 5 point scale. I want to perform regression analysis to check for mediation. How do I go about doing that? Do I have to transform or recode variables? My variables are explained below

Creativity = Q1 + Q2 + Q3    (Do I need to transform Q1-Q3 into single variable representing all three q's of creativity to run regression; if so how to do that?)

Climate    = Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5 + Q6 + Q7 + Q8 (Q1-Q8 into single variable)

Motivation = Q1 + Q2 + Q3 (Q1-Q3 into single variable)

All the questions (Q1, Q2, ...) are measured on a 5 point scale, 1 for strongly disagree and 5 for strongly agree. I want to run below model.

Creativity $=$ constant $+\ \beta_1$ Climate $+\ \beta_2$ Motivation + error

I am using SPSS.

Comment: Is Q1 for Motivation the same as Q1 for Climate, etc? Or are you independently numbering the questions within each domain?

Comment: Search `ordinal independent variables`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Likert scale is also known as summated score. You can **average the score** to get a single variable from different items. Alternatively, you can use **Factor Analysis** for dimension reduction.
2. For multiple regression, you can simply use your model

   ```
   Creativity == constant +  β1 Climate +  β2 Motivation + error
   ```
3. If there is **literature support** for presence of mediation effect. You can use Sobel's test (If sample size is good enough) or bootstraping to test for it.

**Analysis should come after theory. Only on the basis of past evidences, you can take variable 'motivation [or climate] as a mediator or moderator [More complex relationship may occur], analysis for both is different'**

*Make sure to test for model assumptions as well.*